# A question about convergence of power series and its coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

$\textbf{This problem looks simple but it's not actually, please be careful and take it seriously.}$

I found this question from an exam paper of ENS. It has haunted me for months. I've tried lots of ways to solve it, including Abel transformation.

The main difficulty is how to use the condition "$\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum a_nx^n=A$", it's really hard to handle because the formula is a limit of infinite series. You can't estimate it with finite sequence arbitrarily.

The last sub problem of this one is to prove the conclusion when we know $\{a_n\}_n$ are all non-negative, instead of "$\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=0$". This problem is relatively simple and I'm not sure this would help to solve the one I'm asking.

QUESTION:
A real power series $p(x)=\sum_{n\geq0} a_nx^n$ satisfies that $\lim_{x\to1^-}p(x)$ exists and is equal to a real number A. In the meantime, sequence $\{a_n\}_n$ satisfies that $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=0$.

Now I need to prove  $\sum a_n$ exists and is equal to A.

P.S. The main problem is to prove $\sum a_n$ exists. If this has been done, the rest will be easy.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing...

Comment: @MANMAID: I don't know how to prove $\sum a_n=A$. Is there any problem with this exercise? Or this question has been asked yet?

Comment: @MANMAID: Really? Will that help to solve this one? This question has haunted me for months.

Comment: Sir, I clearly stated "something like this" and I didn't say it will solve the problem....

Comment: And seriously!!! "This question has haunted me for months" and yet you got nothing to share about this problem with us!!!

Comment: @MANMAID: Sorry, but I don't get what you mean. Should I say something about this question? Like my experience to solve this question? But indeed I got nothing from it, no conclusion, no possible strategy, no theorem likely to be used. All efforts I made to solve this problem has been proved to be in vain.

Comment: I am new here ... [better you must see here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960)

Comment: @MANMAID: Thank you for that. I'll add something.

Comment: ...Abel's theorem...

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: However, to the best of my knowledge, Abel's theorem states just the contrary, which is that if $\sum a_n<\infty$, then $\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum a_nx^n$ exists. Does this theorem work in the opposite direction?

Comment: Why has the question got so many downvotes? The question is about two versions of Tauberian theorems (which are converse to Abel's theorem) out of which the version with $na_{n} \to 0$ is more popular. +1 to compensate for downvotes.

Comment: Also Tauberian theorems have non-obvious proofs and I don't think we can expect some effort on part of OP. The context of the question as given here should be enough to make it a reasonable question.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Thank you for supporting me. It's really not easy when I don't know this theorem.

Comment: BTW Tauberian theorems are not as famous as usual theorems on infinite series (like ratio test, integral test, root test) but even your original version of the question with no  context should have been sufficient for many people here to recognize it as a Tauberian theorem. I wonder why this was closed. Luckily it got reopened.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: A lot more to learn…orz. We school didn't teach us that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result that you are trying to prove is known as [Tauber's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_and_tauberian_theorems#Tauberian_theorems). By adding and subtracting $p(x)=\sum_1^\infty a_nx^n$ we get
$$\left|\sum_{k=0}^na_n-A\right|\leq \left|\sum_{k=0}^na_k(1-x^k)\right|+\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_kx^k\right|+|p(x)-A|$$
The main idea is now to use the inequality $1-x^k\leq k(1-x)$ together with $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=0$ to dominate the first term, and the rest should not be so difficult.

A classical reference is Titchmarsh: [The Theory of Functions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198533497), p. 10.

Comment: Thank you! You've really done me a big favor!