# If $\lim_{n\to \infty} na_n \to 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n \to S(x)$ $\forall$ $x\in (0,1)$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=S$. Is this false?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

> Question :If $\lim_{n\to \infty} n a_n \to 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n \to S$ for all $x\in (0,1)$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=S$. Is the statement true or false?

If I choose $a_n=\frac{1}{n!}$ (its limit is $0$ when multiplied by n) and $S=e^x$ (I can choose any of the $x\in (0,1)$, but consequently $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=e$. So it should be false.

My problem is that the given answer is true, what is wrong with this counter? Thanks.

Comment: In your statement of "Question" , $\sum a_nx^n$ should be a function relying on $x$. You may need to check your statements. Also, we usually don't say "as $x\in(0,1)$", we say "for all $x\in(0,1)$" or "for some $x\in(0,1)$", and "as $x\to x_0$".

Comment: Thanks @Feng, made an edit.

Comment: As formulated, $S$ is a fixed number, so $\sum a_n x^n$ is equal to $S$, no matter what $x$ is. Is that the intention? Your 'counterexample' $S = e^x$ seems to suggest it is not.

Comment: The first problem is still not resolved, though. You may have not fully understood my words. Let me explain more: When you wrote "$\sum a_nx^n\to S\forall x\in(0,1)$", did you mean "the partial sum $\sum_{n=1}^N a_n x^n\to S$ as $N\to\infty$, for all $x\in(0,1)$"?  If that is the case, then this $S$ should be $S(x)$, a function relying on $x$.  But, this will make your conclusion "$\sum a_n=S$" meaningless. So, you need to explain what did you mean by "$\sum a_nx^n\to S$".

Comment: Apology @Feng, Now?

Comment: for all $x\in(0,1)$.

Comment: If I had to guess, you actually want https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2376768

Comment: Related: see Abel's theorem `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace $S$ with $S(x)$ in the Q. Let $a_1=0$ and $a_n=\frac {1}{n\ln}$ for $n>1.$ So $na_n\to 0.$ If $|x|<1$ then $\sum_na_nx^n$ coverges by comparison to the absolutely convergent series $\sum_nx^n.$ But $\sum_na_n=\sum_n \frac {1}{n\ln}$ does not converge by the Cauchy Condensation Test, or by the Monotone Integral Comparison Test (comparing to $\int_2^{\infty}\frac {1}{x\ln x}dx$ ).

Answer (score 2):

The series is clearly convergent at zero with $sum=a_{0}$.

Also the series is also convergent on $\, (-1,0)$ as a difference

of two convergence series. For each $y\in(-1,0)$ set $y=-x$

where $x\in (0,1)$. Then the series is $T-Q$ where

$T=\sum a_{0}+a_{2}x^{2}+a_{4}x^{4}+.....$  and

$Q=a_{1}x+a_{3}x^{3}+....$ Both $T$ and $Q$ are convergent and

hence the series is convergent on $(-1,0)$ and hence on

$(-1,1)$. Therefore it defines a continuous function on

$(-1,1)$. Thus $limf(x)=f(0)$ which gives $S=a_{0}$. Now we

calculate the right derivative of $f$ at zero. This is

$lim\dfrac{a_{0}+a_{1}x+......-a_{0}}{x}$ which is $a_{1}$.

This is because the term $x(a_{2}+a_{3}x+a_{4}x^{2}+...)$

tends to zero (the infinite sum converges, since $0<x<1$ and
can be taken less than $\dfrac{1}{2}$ and $|a_{n}|<c$ for

$n\geq\,n_{0}$, so we have a finite sum and a geometric

sequence , (after $n_{0}$) which clearly converges.

So the infinite sum is less than a real number M, hence

$x(a_{2}+a_{3}x+a_{4}x^{2}+...)$ tends to zero.

But the nominator is always $S-a_{0}$=$0$, i.e. the derivative is

zero. Thus $a_{1}=0$ and continuing the process we get all

$a_{n}=0$ except $a_{0}$. Therefore the conclusion is correct

(in a trivial way) since $\sum a_{n}=a_{0}=S$

Comment: Of course not! You may have the series $1+0x^{2}+0x^{3}=1$ for all $x$ But the argument is clearly true for any sequence a_{n} with positive terms. (Or non-negative with even one positive term. For alternating series the result is not so obvious but I think it is also true!!.

Comment: Dear Brian, which is the sequence $a_{n}$ in your example? The expansion I calculated gives a sequence {2,-7,6,-2,7,-6,2,-7,6,-2,7,-6,...}. I don't see any sign of decreasing and tending to zero! But by assumption we have $na_{n}\to\,0$ and cleraly $a_{n}$ must tend to zero! Which is not the case here!

Comment: I ignore your insulting, hostile attitude , unworthy of a scientist, and I go to your new example which is "not even wrong" but it is simply wrong! Your new sequence is {2,6,-4,14,-12,8,-28,24,-16,56,-48,32,-112,96,.......}. Do you see any decreasing or any convergence to zero?? Please apologize and delete your previous comment!!

Comment: Dear  Brian, it seems that you didn't notice the initial version of the question for which my answer was written. In the initial version there was no S(x) (as you can still see in the first line of the question, which is left unchanged). In other words the function f(x) defined by the power series was CONSTANT on (0,1)!! So all the counterexamples you mentioned do not apply to the initial form of the question. The OP saw the correction made by one of the answers and changed the title from S to S(x) (in which case the question makes sense). But that was a long time AFTER my answer.

Comment: That hardly makes sense.  I initially commented on your answer over two hours prior to OP changing $S$ to $S(x)$ as a result of DanielWainfleet's answer.  I was speaking specifically to your answer.  To be direct: is it your position that you were just trying to show that a power series that converges on $(0,1)$ to a constant... has all non-constant coefficients equal to $0$ (i.e. the uniqueness of power series coefficients of a power series with positive radius of convergence)?  ... and you wanted to talk about positive coefficients and alternating coefficients for some reason?

Comment: I still contend that the OP has his own question wrong, since the Tauberian theorem is more impactful and very close in form to the original question (without the $S(x)$), but in any case, I've deleted all the previous comments to clean up as they are pointless if my most recent comment has your position correct

Comment: Please visit https://forms.gle/VmGvMb7v3r9S8anj8 question number 1. To avoid question from getting downvoted, I changed the title @BrianMoehring sir.

Comment: The series is clearly convergent at zero with $sum=a_{0}$. Also the series is also convergent on (-1,0) as a difference of two convergence series. For each y\in(-1,0) set y=-x where x\in (0,1). Then the series is